# Is there a way to add/remove an element from an array based on user input

Tags: c++

So you have an array and if the user wants to add an element to it the size of the array increases by 1 and if the user wants to remove an element the size decreases by 1. Is this possible to do with dynamic arrays?

Comment: Dynamic arrays are a misnomer.  They don't automatically expand or contract.  You'll have to reallocate if you want to change the capacity.  See `std::vector`.

Comment: When changing the size of an array (reallocating in *dynamic* memory), the recommendation is to increase by more than one; one strategy is double the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change the number of elements of an array in C++.

However, if you separate the creation of the elements from the allocation of the memory, then it is possible to destroy individual objects in that memory, and you can allocate larger buffer of memory, then copy the elements from the smaller buffer, then destroy the elements from smaller buffer, then decallocate the smaller buffer in order to add more elements than would have fit into capacity of the original buffer.

This abstract data structure is called a "dynamic array". It is important to not confuse this abstract data structure called "dynamic array" with a dynamically allocated C++ array that is also called "dynamic array". A dynamically allocated array in C++ is just an array and its size cannot be changed after it has been created.

There is a container that implements the "dynamic array" data structure in the standard library. It's called `std::vector`.